# Alert dialog in listview from selected item

Tags: android, listview, android-alertdialog

I am having some problems with an alertdialog box. I have a listview containing some strings and when i click the box, it shows an alert dialog box giving the option to book or cancel (its a taxi app). I am trying to get it so the name of the item chosen shows in the alert dialog box. But everytime i try it comes up showing random letters and numbers. Ill post my code as it might make it easier to understand:

Code below -

```
public class TaxiMain extends ListActivity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. 
 * @return */

class Taxi {
    private String taxiName;
    private String taxiAddress;

    public String getName() {
        return taxiName;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        taxiName = name;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return taxiAddress;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        taxiAddress = address;
    }

    public Taxi(String name, String address) {
        taxiName = name;
        taxiAddress = address;
    }
}

public class TaxiAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Taxi> {
    private ArrayList<Taxi> items;
    private TaxiViewHolder taxiHolder;

    private class TaxiViewHolder {
        TextView name;
        TextView address; 
    }

    public TaxiAdapter(Context context, int tvResId, ArrayList<Taxi> items) {
        super(context, tvResId, items);
        this.items = items;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int pos, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;
        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.taxi_list_item, null);
            taxiHolder = new TaxiViewHolder();
            taxiHolder.name = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.taxi_name);
            taxiHolder.address = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.taxi_address);
            v.setTag(taxiHolder);
        } else taxiHolder = (TaxiViewHolder)v.getTag(); 

        Taxi taxi = items.get(pos);

        if (taxi != null) {
            taxiHolder.name.setText(taxi.getName());
            taxiHolder.address.setText(taxi.getAddress());
        }

        return v;
    }
}
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    final String[] taxiNames = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.taxi_name_array);
    final String[] taxiAddresses = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.taxi_address_array);

    ArrayList<Taxi> taxiList = new ArrayList<Taxi>();

    for (int i = 0; i < taxiNames.length; i++) {
        taxiList.add(new Taxi(taxiNames[i], taxiAddresses[i]));
    }

    setListAdapter(new TaxiAdapter(this, R.layout.taxi_list_item, taxiList));  

    final ListView lv = getListView();
    lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, final int position, long id)
        {   

            final int selectedPosition = position;
            AlertDialog.Builder adb=new AlertDialog.Builder(TaxiMain.this); 
             adb.setTitle("Taxi Booking");
             adb.setMessage("You Have Selected: "+taxiNames); 
             adb.setPositiveButton("Book", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                 public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                     Intent intent = new Intent(TaxiMain.this, Booking.class);
                     intent.putExtra("booking",  taxiNames[selectedPosition]);
                     intent.putExtra("address",  taxiAddresses[selectedPosition]);
                     startActivity(intent);
                 }
             });
             adb.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null); 
             adb.show();
         }
     });
```

You'll see at the bottom of the code, theres the line that wont work properly. -

```
adb.setMessage("You Have Selected: "+taxiNames);
```

If anyone can help into seeing why this wont show would be of great help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you type `+taxiNames` you're performing `taxiNames.toString()`. `taxiNames` is an array containing a number of items. You need to just change it to `+ taxiNames[position]`. Or, to keep it in line with your other Taxi objects, you could also use `+ taxiList.get(position).getName()`.

EDIT: Out of curiosity, why are you setting another `final int` for `selectedPosition`? You already have the `final int position` passed in on the method call.

Comment: I think `int position` wasn't originally `final` and was being used elsewhere in the method.  You are correct that `position` could now be used directly.

Comment: cheers bro. it was just for the alert dialog box. finally ive done something correct haha! you have no idea how stressful i find this! praise stack overflow and its users. 

Also do you know why it says that the ismail cartman edited my question? directly above your answer

Comment: @dave: ah okay, makes sense I guess. @Oli: you can click the "edited by" line to see the edits, usually high rep people will edit to fix formatting errors and that sort of thing.

Comment: hey dude! any chance you can take a look at my most recent question and offer some advice? seeing as you know this better than anyone. Cheers bro

Answer (score 2):

taxiNames is an Array, not a String. You should try this:

```
adb.setMessage("You Have Selected: "+taxiNames[selectedPosition]);
```

Comment: cheers man! i had it set to just position before which is why it wasnt working. legend!